# Error starting icCube - Unable to bind address

Tags: iccube

I get the following error starting icCube:

```
icCube Fatal Error IcCube has encountered a fatal error: 
Address already in use: bind 
For more details, please consult your support and/or the log files available in: 
C:\\Users\....\icCube-data\log
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port used by icCube is used by another application (default 8282), so icCube can't listen.

This is more likely because an instance of icCube is already running on the machine (several instances cannot share the same network connection). To stop the running instance you can use the tray icon or the control panel to stop to icCube process.

If it's another application or you want to have several instances of icCube running you can change icCube's port in the configuration file :  [$install/bin/icCube.xml](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/iccube_xml.php).

```
    <!--
        -1 means the HTTP connector is not activated.
        A JAVA system property may by used.
    -->
    <portNumber>8282</portNumber>
```